# how to make wells fixed size bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here i have a situation where i want to make my `map` `well` a `fixed` sized.

here is a **jsfiddle** :  https://jsfiddle.net/x4gM4/36/  (please scroll to note what i was trying)

i have tried what you can see in **jsfiddle**  please help me to make my `map` a `fixed sized`

**here is my main div**

```
<div class="row"> <!-- start of row -->
   <div class="col-sm-6">
         <div class="well"> 4 images goes here </div>   
   </div>

<!-- google map goes here, whom i want to be fixed -->
   <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="well">
          google Map
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- end of one row -->
```

**question:** i want `google map` `well` to be fixed against `scrolling` `images`

> please make jsfiddle size as per below image

[image]

please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you need.

```
div.fixed-map {
  position: relative;
}
div.fixed-map > div.well {
  position: fixed;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4gM4/39/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `position: fixed`

```
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

However, you'll need to set right and top position relative to whole window, not only to the parent div.